# Couldn't find out the clash between two consecutive "end",which causes error

Tags: ruby

In my below code, I put one rescue clause. But I couldn't trace why the two `end` was clashing between them. Could you help me to find out the reason- why so?

***CODE:***

```
n=1
until n > 4 do
  begin
    1/0
    (1..4).each do |l|
      if 'B' == 'B'
        if 1 != 0
          p 'dog'  
        end
      end
      if 'A' == 'A'
        if 1 != 0
          p 'cat'
        end
      end
    end     
    If true == true
      p 'hi'
    end
  rescue
    p 'exception' 
  end
  n=n+1  
end
```

***Error:***

```
E:/WIPData/Ruby/Scripts/test.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, exp
ecting keyword_end
E:/WIPData/Ruby/Scripts/test.rb:71: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expect
ing $end
```

Comment: Before line 64 you are missing an `end` statement. You did not specify the line numbers (why would you, we could just guess them!) so I cannot help you any further... (as I do not like guessing, or counting)

Comment: What kind of program is this, full of "always true" conditionals?

Comment: @Veger I didn't missed anything. And the answer was given by Sergio. I placed the wrong key word. Have you down- vote me for that?

Comment: By the way, with this kind of error, it usually helps to put your code in a IDE and then to auto-format it. You will see the weird indentation somewhere that would help you localize the problem.

Comment: @oldergod I am using `Notepad ++`, and I am very new to this platform. So do not have much knowledge abut the IDE with Ruby. I am doing self teaching- and thought people who are having enough knowledge would help me, but rather killing my post and does insult also. Like you they can also give me some advices to improve, but they didn't. Educated people shouldn't bahave like this way. This is very rude. A better teach can then be proposed to me from here.

Comment: @DoLoveSky I down-voted because you just dumped code, with bad formatting, no line numbers or any additional details. The text at the down-vote button is: *The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. Your question at least covers two of these points!

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev gives a good reason to what was wrong with your code, but the answer to your question is that **`rescue` cannot save syntax errors**. Why? It is pretty much obvious. In order for `rescue` to save an error, the whole program has to be at least parsed successfully. Without that, the `rescue` token itself and the block of code that it is supposed to save would not even be recognized.

Comment: Still down- vote going on? which one is now - `1.research effort` , `2.it is unclear` and `3.not useful`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If true == true
```

Pascal-cased `If` is not a valid ruby keyword. Therefore, its `end` matches another opening keyword instead.

Comment: No, It is just i shorthanded to figure out the `error`. Actual one is too big. But Yes what you mentioned, that was the reason. I have overlooked that part.

Comment: This is a syntactical error causing such errors to produced. Here the main motivation was to find/trac out the error area. Does the code validity rerally need?

Comment: @DoLoveSky no, but some simple indentation, yes.

Comment: @oldergod This really make sense for any down-vote? If you run the code you would get the above mentioned error. But when you fixed the error by `if` from `If`, you can see all are set.

Comment: @DoLoveSky Yes. You are asking people to take time to watch *your* code in order to resolve *your* problem. The least is to make it easy to read.